# Buttons loaded but not displayed Swift

Tags: swift, button, subview

I'm making a simple game with bubbles. When the user loses the buttons float as bubbles, and they pop. When they pop, I remove them from the superview. Everything works fine. When I press New Game, the buttons are loaded correctly, but they are not visible, or maybe visible on different position. What could be the problem?

```
       func lost()
        {

            for i in 0...colorButtons.count-1
            {
                createBubble(sender: colorButtons[i])
            }
        }


    func createBubble(sender : UIButton)
    {

 sender.frame.origin.x = palleteView.frame.origin.x + sender.frame.origin.x

        sender.frame.origin.y = palleteView.frame.origin.y + sender.frame.origin.y

        view.addSubview(sender)

        let zigzagPath = UIBezierPath()
        let oX : CGFloat = sender.frame.origin.x
        let oY : CGFloat = sender.frame.origin.y
        let eX = oX
        let eY = oY - CGFloat(randomFloat(min: 50, max: Float(vl_DeviceHeight-50)))
        let t  : CGFloat = CGFloat(randomFloat(min: 20, max: 100))


        var cp1 = CGPoint(x: oX - t, y: (oX+eY)/2)
        var cp2 = CGPoint(x: oX + t, y: cp1.y)


        let r = random(lower: 0, 1)

        if r == 1
        {
            let temp : CGPoint = cp1
            cp1 = cp2
            cp2 = temp
        }

        zigzagPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: oX, y: oY))
        zigzagPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:eX, y: eY), controlPoint1: cp1, controlPoint2: cp2)

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
            // Every animation added to this transaction is now finished

            UIView.transition(with: sender,
                              duration:0.1,
                              options:UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
                              animations: {

                              sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)

                                // do something
            }, completion:{
                finished in

                sender.removeFromSuperview()

            })
        })

        let pathAnimation : CAKeyframeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        pathAnimation.duration = 2

        pathAnimation.path = zigzagPath.cgPath
        pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        sender.layer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "movingAnimation")

        CATransaction.commit()


    }


  @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) 
  {
        newGame()

        layoutPalleteView(elements: elementString.characters.count)

        for button in colorButtons
        {
            self.palleteView.addSubview(button)

            self.palleteView.bringSubview(toFront: button)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to make it more clear?

Comment: @AhmadF please check now